# How do I create a radial rainbow gradient?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add a rainbow gradient to an existing button. I'm using this brush value

```kotlin
val brush = Brush.radialGradient(
    listOf(
        Color(0xFFFF685D),
        Color(0xFFFF64F0),
        Color(0xFF5155FF),
        Color(0xFF54EDFF),
        Color(0xFF5BFF7B),
        Color(0xFFFDFF59),
        Color(0xFFFFCA55),
    ),
    tileMode = TileMode.Repeated
)
```

This is not achieving the intended effect. It won't even represent a rainbow.

I'm trying to add [image] as a button background gradient.

Comment: do you have an image or link of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Thracian, I've updated the description with the intended effect

Comment: Do you wish to have blur too, without the blur it looks like you need `Brush.sweepgradient`i guess. Is [this gradient](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/typography/opentype/otspec190/images/colr_conic_gradient.png) what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, I intend to replicate the blur

Answer (score 0):

iterate the first element of the float array from 0 to 360 and keep both other  elements at 1
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#HSVToColor(float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#HSVToColor(float%5B%5D))

background info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV